# populate words in each line in the file into temporary array

Tags: bash, shell, grep

```
$ cat file 
line1: Joe Frank tom Jim Michelle Antony
line2: Frank Joe tom Jim Antony Michelle higgs julien
$ arr=`cat file | grep line1`
$ echo $arr 
line1: Joe Frank tom Jim Michelle Antony
$ echo ${arr[1]}
line1: Joe Frank tom Jim Michelle Antony
```

whereas I expected `Joe` as output of `echo ${arr[1]}`

Is there any shortest way to get into temp array the each name in the lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
arr=(`grep line1 file`)
```

or better yet

```
read -a arr < <(grep line1 file)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
grep line1 file | cut -f2 -d " "
```

... check this way